# If I install vmware workstation v7 on top of v6.5, will it use the same lisence key?

Tags: vmware-workstation, licensing

If I install vmware workstation v7 on top of v6.5, will it use the same license key, or do I have to buy a v7 license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMware WS 7 requires a new license key; your 6.x key will not work with 7.  They will allow you to purchase a reduced-price upgrade rather than the full version, though.